# Ogooglebar , ungoogleable or agoogleable?

Tags: slang, dictionaries

If something cant be found after searching on google.
[Ogooglebar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogooglebar#Ungoogleable)  or some other term?
Predictions? Is there already an accepted term?

Comment: The word was originally meant to mean something, that just cannot be found (like you phrased it), but as google sees the connection to things that cannot be found specifically because it has been censored, they put up a lawsuit against it. So I guess facing this precedent, nobody right now bothers to add it as a valid word and   words like ungoogleable are going to be just "well known slang" officially. It just comes too close to "the thing that must not be brought into connection with google" (censoring). Quite an interesting topic, actually. Companies and linguistics...

Comment: @skymninge interesting view

Answer (score 4):

In English the word is *ungoogleable*. *Ogooglebar* is the Swedish word which is sometimes used in English but less commonly.

Both these mean something cannot be found using Google, but may also be used more generically when something cannot be found with any search engine. Google doesn't like this generic use, which resulted in the Swedish Language Council [removing the Swedish word from their annual list of neologisms](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2013/mar/27/google-sweden-ogooglebar) rather than amend the definition.

Comment: -Sometimes- used in English? Maybe so but it would never actually be understood unless you already knew Swedish.

Comment: Unduckduckgoable? Unbingable? Unyahooable? Unlycosable?  Unaskjeevesable?  I would sure bet Google doesn't like the usage, it'll be just like Bayer and aspirin if they let it go.

Comment: @Mitch: Yes, or by people who know this story.

Comment: Yes trademark and verbs.... many a company regrets their trademark entering common language. Especially as a verb.  ie the verb to google. I know people who use that term